# Can we cast spells while we are entangled in a Web spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Can you cast spells while trapped by Web? The spell description sats:

> If the save fails, the creature is entangled and can't move **from it's space**, but can break loose by spending 1 round and making a DC20 Str check or a DC 25 Escape Artist check.

The spell description is clear about the impossibility of moving from its space, but there is no word about the possibility to cast a spell or attack an adjacent ennemy outside of the web. Do you need to break the web before casting or attacking?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. You'll notice that your question was closed then reopened when the game system's tag was added; questions almost always need a game system tag. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 10):

The [*web*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/web.htm) spell's effect can render some creatures [entangled](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#entangled), a condition which can make casting spells and attacking difficult:

> The character is ensnared. Being entangled impedes movement, but does not entirely prevent it unless the bonds are anchored to an immobile object or tethered by an opposing force. **An entangled creature** moves at half speed, cannot run or charge, and **takes a -2 penalty on all attack rolls and a -4 penalty to Dexterity. An entangled character who attempts to cast a spell must make a Concentration check (DC 15 + the spell’s level) or lose the spell.**

Emphasis mine. Otherwise, a creature's casting and attacks are unimpaired by the *web* spell's effect. However, creatures with the *web* spell's effect between them may find combat and spell targeting difficult:

> If you have at least 5 feet of web between you and an opponent, it provides cover. If you have at least 20 feet of web between you, it provides total cover.

Any [cover](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#cover) prevents attacks of opportunity, for instance. And [total cover](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#totalCover) blocks [line of effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#lineofEffect), which most folks need to do pretty much anything to anyone.

#### A quick note on the [*web*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/web.htm) spell's effect

The spell [*web*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/web.htm) does *not* create a lone, giant spider's web that essentially renders creatures that fail the saving throw [helpless](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#helpless) like a spider's web does its prey but creates, instead, a wall-like *mass* of web-like strands that creatures can try to push their way through. The effect *can* secure unlucky, weaker creatures in their spaces, but those creatures are still capable of exerting force and struggling against the strands—and, with difficulty, making attacks and casting spells. So while the spell says, "These strands trap those caught in them," first it says, "[*Web*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/web.htm) creates a many-layered mass of strong, sticky strands." *How* the effect traps affected creatures is governed by the condition [entangled](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#entangled) and the remainder of the spell's description.

Comment: Not sure for your answer, because the spell description sat :

Comment: Once loose (either by making the initial Reflex save or a later strengh check or Escape Artist check) a creature remains entangled, but move through the web very slowly. Each round devoted to moving allow the creature to make a new Str check or Escape artist Check. The creature move 5 feet for EACH full point by which the check result exceed 10

Comment: So if you move only 5 feet above 10 if your save is sucessful, you should not move at half speed if you fail

Comment: @user27997 All of those rules are for a creature that tries to exit a webbed square. If it just *stays* in the webbed square, it can do whatever it wants (within the limits of being entangled, of course). The question wasn't about going from one square to another but about making attacks and casting spells.

Comment: @user27997 If you're  *also* interested in how movement works when a creature fails or succeeds on a saving throw against the spell *web*, you should ask that question. (I'm not trying to give you a hard time or anything, but the site's for asking questions and discourages answering additional questions in comments. However, if you think there's something relevant to attacking and casting in the section you've cited, by all means—, because I'm not seeing it,— make that clearer for me! I learn from answering as much as I learn from asking.)

Comment: My question was not for the movement. But I don't think the word "entangle" in the spell description was use for the "entangle condition". The word was use in a different way, like a trap. If that was like the entangle condition, you would move in the same way .

Comment: @user27997 While sometimes developers lack synonyms, I don't think this is one of those cases. *Creatures caught within a web become entangled among the gluey fibers* is maybe purely descriptive, but *If this save succeeds, the creature is entangled, but not prevented from moving, though moving is more difficult than normal for being entangled (see below)*, I think *isn't* being just descriptive with the word *entangled*, as the spell then describes movement that's different from how an entangled creature usually moves while entangled, which is necessary for the sentence's sense.

Comment: @user27997 It sounds like you want an answer that says that *A creature can't cast spells or make attacks while affected by a* web *spell because the game uses the word* entangled *descriptively rather than mechanically, therefore the DM must house rule what* entangled *means in this case, and most reasonable folks would say that an* entangled *creature can neither cast spells nor attack.* Is that accurate?

Comment: loll!!!  No... i'm the DM. I only want know if a character can cast a spell while he's trapped in a Web spell. But the spell description is unclear about the answer.